# YOLO v2 loss function

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to understand (and implement) the YOLOv2 loss function, which is not given explicitly in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08242).

There are several posts on this topic, but quite a few seem to confuse the YOLOv1 and YOLOv2 loss functions.

The following discussion of the three contributions to the loss function is based on [Yumi's blog](https://fairyonice.github.io/Part_4_Object_Detection_with_Yolo_using_VOC_2012_data_loss.html), fixing some typos along the way. This seems to be one of the more complete discussions, but I'm still confused about various aspects.

My specific questions are interleaved with the text, I'd be really grateful if someone could clarify these points.

#### Total loss function

The total loss is given by

$$
\text{loss} = \sum_{i=1}^{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^B \left(\text{loss}_{i,j}^{xywh} + \text{loss}_{i,j}^p + \text{loss}_{i,j}^c\right)
$$

Here $i=1,\dots,S^2$ is the index of the gridcell and $j=1,\dots,B$ is the index of the anchor box slot. Each of the three terms in the loss function will be scaled by a hyperparameter; these hyperparameters are denoted as $\lambda_{\text{coord}}$, $\lambda_{\text{class}}$ and $\lambda_{\text{obj}}$ below.## Heading ##

Define the following indicator function:
$$
L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $C_{i,j}=1$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
where $C_{i,j}$ is the ground truth that there is an object associated with anchor box $j$ in grid cell $i$.

Further let

$$
N_{L^{\text{obj}}} = \sum_{i=1}^{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^B L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}.
$$

##### Question

- Isn't therefore $L^{\text{obj}}_{i,j}=C_{i,j}$? Why introduce an additional variable?

#### Loss due to bounding box mismatch (coordinate loss)

$$
\text{loss}_{i,j}^{xywh} = \frac{\lambda_{\text{coord}}}{N_{L^{\text{obj}}}} L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\left[\left(x_{i,j}-\hat{x}_{i,j}\right)^2+\left(y_{i,j}-\hat{y}_{i,j}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{w_{i,j}}-\sqrt{\hat{w}_{i,j}}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{h_{i,j}}-\sqrt{\hat{h}_{i,j}}\right)^2\right]
$$

Here $x_{i,j}, y_{i,j}, w_{i,j}, h_{i,j}$ are the true coordinates of the centre and width/height of the bounding box associated with grid cell $i$ and anchor box $j$. The corresponding predicted values $\hat{x}_{i,j}, \hat{y}_{i,j}, \hat{w}_{i,j}, \hat{h}_{i,j}$ are indicated with a hat. Since each term is multiplied by $L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\in\{0,1\}$, the coordinate loss only contributes for those $i,j$ which correspond to a true bounding box.

##### Question

- Why is the bounding box loss divided by $N_{L^{\text{obj}}}$? This seems to imply that for images with a large number of ground truth boxes each of the terms carries less weight. Why is this desirable?

#### Classification loss

Let $p_{i,j}^{c}\in\{0,1\}$ be the ground truth probability that the object associated with $i,j$ is of class $c\in\text{classes}$. The corresponding predicted probabilities $\hat{p}_{i,j}^c$ are denoted with a hat. Then the classification loss in $i,j$ is given by the cross-entropy

$$
\text{loss}_{i,j}^{c} = -\frac{\lambda_{\text{class}}}{N_{L^{\text{obj}}}} L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}} \sum_{c\in\text{classes}} p_{i,j}^c \log\left(\hat{p}_{i,j}^c\right).
$$

Again, since we multiply each term by $L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\in\{0,1\}$, only those $i,j$ which are associated with a real object contribute.

##### Questions

- Why is the cross-entropy $-\sum_{c\in\text{classes}} p_{i,j}^c \log\left(\hat{p}_{i,j}^c\right)$ used instead of something like $\sum_{c\in\text{classes}}\left(p_{i,j}^c-\hat{p}_{i,j}^c\right)^2$? The latter seems to be what is used in the YOLOv1 loss function.
- Same question as for the coordinate loss: why is classification loss divided by $N_{L^{\text{obj}}}$?

#### Confidence loss

Define

$$
L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $\max_{i',j'}\left\{\text{IoU}\left(\mathcal{B}(x_{i',j'},y_{i',j'},w_{i',j'},h_{i',j'}),\mathcal{B}(\hat{x}_{i,j},\hat{y}_{i,j},\hat{w}_{i,j},\hat{h}_{i,j})\right)\right\} < 0.6$ and $C_{i,j}=0$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Here $\mathcal{B}(x,y,w,h)$ denotes the bounding box with centre coordinate $x,y$ and width/height $w,h$. $\text{IoU}\left(\mathcal{B}_a,\mathcal{B}_b\right)$ is the intersection over union measure of two bounding boxes $\mathcal{B}_a$ and $\mathcal{B}_b$.

Further, let

$$
N^{\text{conf}} = \sum_{i=1}^{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^B\left(L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}+L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}\left(1-L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\right)\right).
$$

Then the confidence loss is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{loss}_{i,j}^{c} &= \frac{\lambda_{\text{obj}}}{N^{\text{conf}}} L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\left(\text{IoU}\left(\mathcal{B}(x_{i,j},y_{i,j},w_{i,j},h_{i,j}),\mathcal{B}(\hat{x}_{i,j},\hat{y}_{i,j},\hat{w}_{i,j},\hat{h}_{i,j})\right)-\hat{C}_{i,j}\right)^2\\
&\quad+\;\; \frac{\lambda_{\text{noobj}}}{N^{\text{conf}}} L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}\left(0-\hat{C}_{i,j}\right)^2
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\hat{C}_{i,j}$ is the predicted confidence of finding an object in $i,j$ (I think that in [Yumi's blog](https://fairyonice.github.io/Part_4_Object_Detection_with_Yolo_using_VOC_2012_data_loss.html) a square is missing in the second line).

##### Questions

- What is the interpretation of $\max_{i',j'}\left\{\text{IoU}\left(\mathcal{B}(x_{i',j'},y_{i',j'},w_{i',j'},h_{i',j'}),\mathcal{B}(\hat{x}_{i,j},\hat{y}_{i,j},\hat{w}_{i,j},\hat{h}_{i,j})\right)\right\} < 0.6$ in the definition of $L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}$? It seems the say: *"$i,j$ is deemed to not contain an object if the ground truth is that is doesn't contain an object and there is no other $i',j'$ such that the predicted $i,j$ bounding has more than 0.6 overlap with the $i',j'$ ground truth bounding box"*.  Why is this term required and why don't we simply set $L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}=1-C_{i,j}$?
- Since $C_{i,j}=L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}$, $L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}=1$ implies that $L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}=0$. Hence, it seems that $L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}\left(1-L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}\right)$ can we simplified to $L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}$, and therefore $N^{\text{conf}} = \sum_{i=1}^{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^B\left(L_{i,j}^{\text{obj}}+L_{i,j}^{\text{noobj}}\right).$ Am I missing something here?
- What is the interpretation of $N^{\text{conf}}$?
- Again, what is the rationale behind dividing the confidence loss by $N^{\text{conf}}$?